# Get custom post type by category in a page template

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've created a custom post type with categories and sub categories, what I need to do is list out the post titles and images for a given sub-category or category in a page template.

I've got as far as getting the all the listed items in the custom post type, but I'm unsure how to go further... any help appreciated.

```
<?php 
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
the_title();
echo '<div class="entry-content">';
the_content();
echo '</div>';
endwhile;
?>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it's possible the below code did not work because it uses a deprecated parameter (I *think* caller_get_posts was deprecated in 3.1)

Think the below should sort things out:

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type' => 'portfolio', 
    'cat' => 5, // Whatever the category ID is for your aerial category
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'orderby' => 'date', // Purely optional - just for some ordering
    'order' => 'DESC' // Ditto
) );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
```

Couple of things to consider as well (sorry if this crosses into 'obvious' territory!):

1) is your custom post type registered to use the built in categories or is it a custom taxonomy that it's using? If the former then the above should work, if the latter then you would need to use 'your-taxonomy-name'=>'your-taxonomy-term' in place of the cat=>5 parameter

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters

2) Do you have any other loops running on the page?  If so they will need

```
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

after them in order for subsequent loops to work properly

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
$cat_id = get_cat_ID('My Category'); //the categories name
$args=array(
  'cat' => $cat_id,
  'post_type' => 'portfolio',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'caller_get_posts'=> 1
);
$new = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: Sadly it still returns the headlines of all posts in portfolio, not the 5 in the aerial category...